# Change same line of code in multiple RMD or R files

Tags: r

1. Is there a way to change the same line of code in multiple RMD or R script files instead of manually going in to each file and changing it?
2. also is there a way to change the first chunk of multiple RMD files to something else instead of manually doing it? The code in the first chunk of each RMD file isn't exactly the same but I want to change the entire first chunk of each RMD file to some other code.

Comment: Might be good situation to write a function to live in either a separate script or a package, so you can reference it each place you need it, but maintain it in only one place. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward option here is to create a separate R script file that performs the process included in the R line or the RMD chunk and simply source that script file in all of the separate R script files or RMD files that use it. Then when you need to change that process you simply edit the external sourced script file.